# How to Copy Data Filter Between MID MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

We have a multi MID enterprise environment in Marketing Cloud. I have built a very complex data filter for a shared data extension that is used across MIDs. I would like to copy the filter from the parent to the child MIDs instead of always editing at the parent level. It seems that it is not possible to move a filter into the shared data extensions area the same way you can do with filtered Data extensions. Is there some way to use the filter text to re-create the filter at the child MID? If there is another solution to achieve the same thing, I am happy for that as well.

My only solution that I am trying to avoid is rebuilding the exact same filter in each child MID. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do: Ensure the source Data Extension is located in the *Shared Items* section, login to one of the child business units, access the filtered Data Extension, and select the **Save as Filter** button within the properties section. Save that data filter in the child business unit, repeat process for any other data filters needed, and then switch to the next child business unit.

If you're familiar with the API library there may be a more efficient way of going about this, but this the 'easiest' way I believe, and at least stops you from redoing the drag-and-drop process.

Comment: Two issues here - one is that the data extension is not the same source DE. Second is that from the child MID, ability to access filter is not available.